# Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall event (subiquity/Network/_send_update: CHANGE eth0)

Tags: installation, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04, packer

I'm building an Ubuntu 20.04 VM using packer and I'm having a strange issue with the build. On VM console during build time I'm receiving a lot of messages:

'ubuntu-server subiquity_event.1890[1890]: subiquity/Network/_send_update: CHANGE eth0'

At the end of the install, when Ubuntu is updating the packages, the log is filled up with this notification and I'm not able to check anything else in the console.

These messages are polluting the console log and sometimes the build fails but without being able to catch the error due to the message above. I searched the internet about the cause of this but without any luck.

I have uploaded on pastebin the installer-journal of a successful build that has its logs filled with the subituity_event.1890.

Log: https://pastebin.com/ELxy361r

Packer template: https://pastebin.com/sM30Ktdk

User-data: https://pastebin.com/GQPsZTbc

Does anyone encountered this event? Can I do something to reduce this event from triggering?

Comment: After a couple of tries I found out that it looks like the issue is caused by the Hyper-V switch. I tried a new build using Default Switch (NAT one) and now the build is working fine.

The issue seems to be related to the external switch(Bridge) but I'm not able to understand what could cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of more builds I found out that event is caused by the lack of IPv6 from my home network. The modem my ISP provided supports only IPv4.

To resolve the issue I started the installation with one additional kernel parameter ipv6.disable=1.

Comment: where did you add this information? in the Packer file? I seem to be getting the same problem